# How to assign a string literal from a string array to a string pointer in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, string-literals

I'm trying to create a program where you can use WASD to move a player around a screen. What I'm trying to do is assign a string to a string pointer. I try to initialize the string pointer, assign the string from a string array to the string pointer, but it generates the error:

`warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char*' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint conversion]`

The occurrence happens at `*CurrentString = &AllStrings[1];` and `*CurrentString = &AllStrings[(printCol + 1)];`.

I'll tell you about how it works. There is a 4x4 grid, `row` represents y-values from 1-4 assigned to each row of the grid, `column` represents x-values from 1-4 assigned to each column of the grid. When either variable changes, the row/column that an icon representing the player changes. Then the icon's location is modified to fit the new parameters (e.g. if the icon is on (2, 2) and the player moves left, the new location is (1, 2). Current screen is cleared, new screen is printed where the icon is on (1, 2).)

Here is some of my code. I had to cut off about half of if for the sake of brevity:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int printBy;
    int printCol;
    int Verify = 0;
    char player_response;
    char *AllStrings[5] = {"    ", "O   ", " O  ", "  O ", "   O"};
    char *CurrentString; //declaring CurrentString
    *CurrentString = &AllStrings[1];
    *CurrentString = AllStrings[1];
    
    printf("\n%s", *CurrentString);
    x = 1;
    while (x < 4) {
        printf("\n%s", AllStrings[0]);
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
    do {
        scanf("%c", &player_response);

        switch(player_response) {
            case 'w':
                system("clear");
                row -= row; //`row` ascends in value top to bottom, starting at 0.
                for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    if (row == x) {
                        printBy = x;
                        Verify = 1;
                    }
                } //end for
                if (Verify != 1) {
                    row += row;
                }
                if (Verify == 1) {
                    while (y < printBy) {
                        printf("\n%s", AllStrings[0]);
                        y++;
                    }
                    printf("\n%s", *CurrentString);
                    y = (row + 1);
                    while (y < 4) {
                        printf("\n%s", AllStrings[0]);
                        y++;
                    }
                } //end if
                y = 0; x = 0;
                Verify = 0;
                break;
```

How is this happening if this is how you normally assign a value to a pointer? I tried to remove indirection operators on each occurrence of `CurrentString`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of pointers to string literals

```
char *AllStrings[5] = {"    ", "O   ", " O  ", "  O ", "   O"};
```

That is each element of the array has the type `char *`.

So to assign a pointer that points to a (first character of a ) string literal just write

```
char *CurrentString; //declaring CurrentString
CurrentString = AllStrings[1];
```

And to print the string literal write for example

```
printf( "%s\n", CurrentString );
```

or

```
puts( CurrentString );
```

Pay attention to that in this while loop

```
x = 1;
while (x < 4) {
    printf("\n%s", AllStrings[0]);
    x++;
}
```

there is outputted the same string literal `AllStrings[0]` three times.